# How to add a check mark to an NSMenuItem

Tags: cocoa, menu

In a contextual menu, how can I give an NSMenuItem a check mark? I want to place it next to specific items. I create the menu in the `mouseDown:` function, as shown below:

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
NSPoint pointInView = [self convertPoint:[event locationInWindow] fromView:nil];

if (NSPointInRect(pointInView, [self shapeRect]) )
{       
    NSMenu *theMenu = [[[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"default Contextual Menu"] autorelease];

    [theMenu insertItemWithTitle:@"Circle" action:@selector(circle:) keyEquivalent:@"" atIndex:0];
    [theMenu insertItemWithTitle:@"Rectangle" action:@selector(rectangle:) keyEquivalent:@"" atIndex:1];

    [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:theMenu withEvent:event forView:self];        
}   
}
```

How can I give the items a check mark?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "check". Do you mean you want to place a checkmark next to specific items, or that you want to test for the available items in the menu?

Comment: i want to place a checkmark next to specific items
thanks for quick reply

Answer (score 21):

Take a look at the [`NSUserInterfaceItemValidations`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSUserInterfaceValidations_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol. When a menu is displayed, it will query each responder in the responder chain with `validateUserInterfaceItem:` method to determine if the item should be enabled. (An item will be enabled so long as one responder in the chain returns `YES`) This also gives you an opportunity to customize the item. For example:

```
- (BOOL)validateUserInterfaceItem:(id <NSValidatedUserInterfaceItem>)item {
    if ([item action] == @selector(actionMethodForItemThatShouldBeChecked:)] {
        // This method is also used for toolbar items, so it's a good idea to 
        // make sure you're validating a menu item here
        if ([item respondsToSelector:@selector(setState:)])
            [item setState:NSControlStateValueOn];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This seems abusive of the responder chain system

Comment: @Ky-: <https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000261-SW1>: "validateMenuItem: is also a good place to toggle titles or set state on menu items to make sure they're always correct." That's exactly what the system is for. Though I suppose the docs suggest using `validateMenuItem:` instead of `validateUserInterfaceItem:` if you're going to adjust state.

Comment: @thakis right; that's why I upvoted [DavidA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33549582/453435) and didn't even comment there. It's more in-line with how AppKit was designed. Though, I'd recommend just setting the state with whatever direct reference you have, or using tags, rather than selectors

Answer (score 11):

You want something like this:

```
// Place a check mark next to "Circle"
NSMenuItem * theItem = [theMenu indexOfItemWithTitle: @"Circle"];
[item setState: NSOnState];
```

You would use NSOffState to remove the check mark.

Comment: I think that checking for the menu-item's title is a bad idea.  Wouldn't it be better to check what it's action is?  The action wouldn't be as likely to change as the menu-item's title would be.

Answer (score 8):

Using the `NSMenuValidation` protocol you can do this:

```
-(BOOL)validateMenuItem:(NSMenuItem *)menuItem
{
    if(menuItem.action==@selector(actionMethodForItemThatShouldBeChecked:))
    {
        menuItem.state=NSControlStateValueOn;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe that **NSOnState** is deprecated (first deprecated in macOS 10.14), you can use `NSControlStateValueOn` instead. Ex:

```
[myItem setState: NSControlStateValueOn];
```

For more information check [here](https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/NSOnState.html)

Answer (score 6):

In Swift you can check an `NSMenuItem` like this:

```
let myItem: NSMenuItem = ...
myItem.state = .on
```

For more information check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/statevalue